# C Masking Password with getch() using ncurses Library

Tags: c, ncurses, getch

I have this simple Program and i have achieved hiding password with *.

```
printf("Password: ");

initscr();
noecho();

char passwd[MAX_PASS]
int p=0; 
    do{ 
        passwd[p]=getch(); 
        if(passwd[p]!='\n'){ 
            printw("*"); 
        } 
        p++; 
    }while(passwd[p-1]!='\n'); 
    passwd[p-1]='\0';

endwin();
```

Im able to mask the password with '*' . The problem is that the first print won't show in my terminal, until endwin(); happens i think , when i get back what was printed in the terminal before.....
any clues why and how im going to fix that?
I mean, i want to show the first printf and the printf's before that.

Comment: You have to call `refresh()` after every `printw()` so that ncurses flushes the buffer to the terminal.

Comment: that is not the problem. To make it more clear. The problem is that when entering the initscr(); , my terminal is like opening another terminal and im giving the password and after that it brings all the printf's before initscr() back!!
It is like, after initscr() my terminal clears and after endwin() it brings back all everything before initscr() and disappers the aterisks(*)

Comment: When you move into ncurses, you obscure everything from before. So you'd need to print "Password: " using ncurses, rather than `stdio.h`

Comment: i see, im starting to get. Need to test it more.

Answer (score 1):

The comment by @anonmess is close: when initializing curses (in `initscr`), the terminal description's `smcup` and `rmcup` capabilities may cause the terminal to switch into *alternate screen* while in curses mode, and then back out, showing the `Password:` on the *normal screen*.  Alternate-screen is an xterm feature that's copied into a lot of terminal emulators, but it [confuses some people](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#xterm_tite).

It's possible (but not a good idea) to do `printf` while in curses mode:

- the printf output confuses ncurses (it doesn't know that the `printf` may have moved the cursor it will put text in the wrong place), and
- `printf` is buffered, so you'd have to do an `fflush(stdout)` to even see the `printf` output.

ncurses does an `fflush(stdout)` before switching into curses mode, so your `Password:` does get flushed out to the normal screen.  Before ncurses 6.0, it did not do that (curses output used the same output buffers as `printf`), but that turned out to be a bad idea (read the [release notes for 6.0](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/announce-6.0.html#h3-lib-setbuf)).

Comment: i see, so in other words the only thing i can do is use prinw instead of printf i assume.....

Comment: You could use the `filter` function, for one-line displays (the ncurses example shows how to suppress the alternate screen for that case).